# How to properly align two numbered equations?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, amsmath, arrays, alignat

I try to type two following equations:

[image]

These equations are not subequations. First number 1 in (1.1) and (1.2) means chapter. My problem is that each part of these equations is centering. I can't reproduce this alignment.

First I tried `alignat` environment from `amsmath` package:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{alignat}{9}
        M \ddot x & + & D_s \dot x & + & K x & = & F \cos(\omega t + \delta)  & + & P \cos{\gamma} \\[6pt]
        \underset{\substack{\text{inertia} \\ \text{force}}}{M \ddot y} & + &
        \underset{\substack{\text{damping} \\ \text{force}}}{D_s \dot y} & + &
        \underset{\substack{\text{stiffness} \\ \text{force}}}{K y} & = &
        \underset{\substack{\text{rotating external} \\ \text{exciting force}}}{F \sin(\omega t + \delta)} & + &
        \underset{\substack{\text{constant radial} \\ \text{load force}}}{P \sin{\gamma}}
    \end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

The result is following:

[image]

Something close to what I need, but horizontal alignment needs.

I tried to search and found that `array` is the best to fit alignment needs.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{array}{c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}c@{\,}}
        M \ddot x & + & D_s \dot x & + & K x & = & F \cos(\omega t + \delta)  & + & P \cos{\gamma} \\
        \underset{\substack{\text{inertia} \\ \text{force}}}{M \ddot y} & + &
        \underset{\substack{\text{damping} \\ \text{force}}}{D_s \dot y} & + &
        \underset{\substack{\text{stiffness} \\ \text{force}}}{K y} & = &
        \underset{\substack{\text{rotating external} \\ \text{exciting force}}}{F \sin(\omega t + \delta)} & + &
        \underset{\substack{\text{constant radial} \\ \text{load force}}}{P \sin{\gamma}}
    \end{array}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `array` I solved alignment issues, but now I can't number every line of these two equations.

Then I found `eqnarray` package:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, eqnarray}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    
    \vspace*{30\baselineskip}
    
    \bgroup\arraycolsep 0.1em
    \begin{equationarray}{*{9}{c}}
        M \ddot x & + & D_s \dot x & + & K x & = & F \cos(\omega t + \delta)  & + & P \cos{\gamma} \label{eq1} \\[6pt]
        \underset{\substack{\text{inertia} \\ \text{force}}}{M \ddot y} & + &
        \underset{\substack{\text{damping} \\ \text{force}}}{D_s \dot y} & + &
        \underset{\substack{\text{stiffness} \\ \text{force}}}{K y} & = &
        \underset{\substack{\text{rotating external} \\ \text{exciting force}}}{F \sin(\omega t + \delta)} & + &
        \underset{\substack{\text{constant radial} \\ \text{load force}}}{P \sin{\gamma}} \label{eq2}
    \end{equationarray}
    \egroup
    
    
    Equations \ref{eq1} and \ref{eq2} have\ldots
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Firstly I thought I solved my problem, but when I clicked on red links to equations, I was scrolled to the top of pdf page...

What should I use to make horizontal alignment?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `IEEEeqnarray` from `IEEEtrantools`. Here I specify alternating centered columns, one for ordinary material and one for relation/operation symbols.

I also add a simpler syntax for the descriptions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\explain}[2]{\underset{\explain@{#1}}{\mathstrut#2}}
\newcommand{\explain@}[1]{%
  \textnormal{%
    \fontsize{\sf@size}{\fpeval{\sf@size*1.2}}\selectfont
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{cCcCcCcCc}
M \ddot{x} & + &
  D_s \dot{x} & + &
  Kx & = &
  F \cos(\omega t + \delta) & + &
  P \cos{\gamma}
\\[6pt]
\explain{inertia \\ force}{M \ddot y} & + &
  \explain{damping \\ force}{D_s \dot y} & + &
  \explain{stiffness \\ force}{K y} & = &
  \explain{rotating external \\ exciting force}{F \sin(\omega t + \delta)} & + &
  \explain{constant \\ radial \\ load force}{P \sin{\gamma}}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you reduce space between text lines under equation? For example between words «inertia» and «force». Unfortunately, I'm still LaTeX beginner, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I found a way to reduce space between text lines myself: `\sf@size*1.2` → `\sf@size` (remove coefficient 1.2).

Comment: @Sindzicat I'not do it, you get uneven rows. You will see that “force” is in different vertical positions under “inertia” and ”damping”.

Comment: sorry, I tried to see this uneven rows (please see my [screenshot](https://habrastorage.org/webt/pk/g4/ye/pkg4ye2yykq-edo3uxf7vlck5xe.png) with screnrule) and unfortunately I don't see anything bad. Could you give me screenshot or something other that demonstrate this?

Comment: @Sindzicat Do as you prefer. But I added a missing `\mathstrut` before `#2`. It's needed.

Answer (score 9):

In your case you could use the `eqparbox` package for example. It helps to make pairs of boxes of the same width. After making them, it is sufficient to use simple `align' for your equations to be properly aligned.

The example could be like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    
    \vspace*{30\baselineskip}
    
    \begin{align}
      \eqmakebox[a]{$M \ddot x$} +
      \eqmakebox[b]{$D_s \dot x$} +
      \eqmakebox[c]{$K x$} &=
      \eqmakebox[d]{$F \cos(\omega t + \delta)$} +
      \eqmakebox[e]{$P \cos{\gamma}$} \label{eq1} \\[6pt]
      \eqmakebox[a]{$\underset{\substack{\text{inertia} \\ \text{force}}}{M \ddot y}$} +
      \eqmakebox[b]{$\underset{\substack{\text{damping} \\ \text{force}}}{D_s \dot y}$} +
      \eqmakebox[c]{$\underset{\substack{\text{stiffness} \\ \text{force}}}{K y}$} &=
      \eqmakebox[d]{$\underset{\substack{\text{rotating external} \\ \text{exciting force}}}{F \sin(\omega t + \delta)}$} +
      \eqmakebox[e]{$\underset{\substack{\text{constant radial} \\ \text{load force}}}{P \sin{\gamma}}$} \label{eq2}
    \end{align}
    Equations \eqref{eq1} and \eqref{eq2} have\ldots
    
\end{document}
```

The result:
[image]

Comment: Thank a lot, @SergeiGolovan! I didn't hear about `eqparbox` before. I'd like to ask only one moment. You said «for example» Did you mean there are several ways to solve this problem?

Comment: I would say that there're always other ways. For example (again), you can use `\underset{\hphantom{\substack{...}}{...}` in the first equation to make formulas in it the same width as in the second one.

Comment: It's interesting and so simple idea! Thanks a lot!